# Python strip String before character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have DAT file which contains the payload XML , each line contain one payload XML and line ends with `EOT 2021-07-29 08:16:36` , here EOT is control character.

I am trying to grab my payload before the control Character, I tried below code but its not able give desired output

here is my DAT file data sample

```
<A> <B> </B> </A>EOT021-07-29 08:16:36
<E> <F> </F> </E>EOT2021-07-29 08:16:36
so on ...
```

From above i just want to read each line before the control character 'EOT' for e.g. like below ouput

```
<A> <B> </B> </A>
<E> <F> </F> </E>
```

Here is my code

```
infile = open('FILE.dat')
for line in infile:
    # Typical line: variable = value
   # value = line.split('EOT')
    #value = value.strip()  # remove leading/traling blanks
    print(line.strip('EOT'))
    break
infile.close()
```

I tried all above code commented as well but not getting the proper result. any thoughts?
Using python 3.X.

Comment: i would recommand `"EOT".join(line.strip().split("EOT")[:-1])`

Comment: as mentioned EOT is control character so using EOT to find will not work.. if I open DAT file in Notepad++ then control Character shows as EOT. (<Control CHAR>2021-07-29 08:16:3) Is that something I can use to grab the text before control Character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with string slicing:

```
line[:line.find(chr(4))]
```

Comment: as mentioned EOT is control character so using EOT to find will not work.. if I open DAT file in Notepad++ then control Character shows as EOT. (<Control CHAR>2021-07-29 08:16:3) Is that something I can use to grab the text before control Character?

Comment: Updated answer to find actual control character, not 'EOT' string